# How do I retrieve Stripe plan name from API?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the current plan name for a customer from the following code.

```
$stripeid = [Stripe Customer ID stored in DB]
$cu1 = \Stripe\Customer::Retrieve( array("id" => $stripeid));
$subscription = $cu1->data->object->lines->data[0]->plan->name;
```

$subscription does not return a value.  My test customer has a single subscription plan on their account.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object it looks like it should be `$cu1->subscriptions->data[0]->plan->name`

Comment: Thank you!  That works perfectly.